# How to connect Visual Studio for Mac Project to Azure Data Studio database?

Tags: asp.net, azure, docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using an M1 Max MacBook and am using docker to run Azure SQL Edge. I have a database created in Azure Data Studio with the location "localhost" and name "localhost".

I am following along a ASP.NET Core tutorial and am trying to figure out how to rewrite the AppSettings.json file to access the database I created. Right now I can't figure out how to connect the database I have to my project in Visual Studio for Mac. My end goal is to run to able to run 'dotnet ef database update' in my project to update that said database. Sorry if this is hard to follow, I am a really big noob. But this is what I have right now in the AppSettings.json file:

```
  {"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Error"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CodeCamp": "Data Source=localhost;User Id=sa;Password=MyPass@word; Initial Catalog=PSCodeCamp;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can read this article and refer to its steps:https://database.guide/how-to-install-azure-data-studio-on-a-mac/

Answer (score 1):

As of now you have already added your **Database Connection string** in `appsettings.json`. looks like below

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    },
}
```

Once you added your connection string in a `appsettings.json`. check the `Startup.cs` file, and find a method called '**ConfigureServices**' add the dependency injection there.

To configured in `Startup.cs` with the connection string being read from configuration. Note the `GetConnectionString()` method looks for a configuration value whose key is `ConnectionStrings:<connection string name>`. You need to import the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration) namespace to use this extension method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDatabase")));
}
```

Refer here [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core) & [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac)